# Como finalizar uma activity a partir de outra classe?

Tags: java, android

Preciso fechar uma activity se ela tiver aberta, quando um determinado timer terminar, como faço isso ? pois para usar o finish eu preciso de contexto.

Tentei fazer um cast, mas sem sucesso:

```
if (dados.getvideorodando()){
  try {
    ((Video2)getApplicationContext()).finish();
  }catch (Exception e){
     Log.e(TAG,"Erro ao fechar actitivy " + e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um broadcast, que serviria como um listener na sua activity.

Considerando que você está em uma activity B e está tentando fechar uma activity A.

ActivityA.java

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Esse método será chamado ao lançar um broadcast
            // pela activity B
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        // Aqui você registra o seu BroadcastReceiver
        // para escutar um broadcast que tenha a ação "meuFiltro".
        // Você pode alterar esse valor para qualquer outro,
        // desde que também altere na sua activity B
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
            .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("meuFiltro"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Se essa activity for destruída por alguma outra forma,
        // você não vai precisar finalizá-la pela activity B,
        // pois ela já estará destruída
        // Então aqui o BroadcastReceiver é removido
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
            .unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

ActivityB.java

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...

    private void fechaActivityA() {
        // Aqui você envia um broadcast e qualquer activity
        // que tiver um BroadcastReceiver registrado com
        // essa mesma action "meuFiltro", será chamado o
        // método onReceive() do BroadcastReceiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("meuFiltro"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Não estou em outra activity estou num service, e já tenho um broadcast rodando, teria como reutilizar, pra não precisar criar outro?

Comment: Sim, ao enviar o broadcast, você pode passar um booleano dentro da `Intent` indicando que é pra fechar a `activity` e dentro do `onReceive` do `BroadcastReceiver` você pega a `Intent`, checa esse booleano e fecha a `activity`. Estou explicando dessa forma, porque acredito que você já tenha bastante conhecimento em Android. Se achar necessário, posso atualizar a resposta com o que acabei de dizer.

Comment: Funcionou, fiz esse do boolean que você disse, obrigado.